# Convert to Strictly increasing integer array with minimum changes

Tags: arrays, algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

Given an array `{a0,a1,a2,a3,a4,.....an}`.I need to find the minimum number of replacements of number to make the array strictly increasing.
I know that there exists dynamic programming solutions for the question.

> https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-to-strictly-increasing-integer-array-with-minimum-changes/

I have been trying out a greedy solution for the problem.

This is the Pseudo Code - (Greedy)

1. Start iterating on the array `from a[1]` (0-based indexing).
2. `if a[i] > a[i-1] then continue`
3. `else` -

   1. `if (a[i-2]+1 < a[i] && a[i-1] != a[i-2]+1) , then make a[i-1] = a[i-2] + 1`
   2. `else make a[i] = a[i-1] + 1`
4. Continue till end of array.

Basic approach is, that if an out of order element is found(a[i]) then first check if the previous element 
(a[i-1]) can be decreased or not. 
If it is possible to decrease it check if decreasing it to the minimum possible number changes the fact that a[i] < a[i-1] or not.
If it make no change to that fact then don't decrease `a[i-1]`, instead increase a[i] to `a[i-1] + 1`.

---

eg - 3 2 5 3 8 4 4

1. 2<3, so decrease 3 to 0. Array becomes - 0 2 5 3 8 4 4
2. 5>2 so continue.
3. 3<5, decreasing to 3 and 4 is possible but not effective. So increase 3 to 6. Array - 0 2 5 6 8 4 4
4. 8>6 so continue
5. 4<8, decreasing 8 to 7 is possible but not effective. Array - 0 2 5 6 8 9 4
6. 4<9, decreasing 9 to 8 is not possible, so increase 4 to 10. Array - 0 2 5 6 8 9 10
7. Total changes = 4. Giving the answer in O(n).

---

I have been trying to prove the greedy strategy wrong but have been unable to do so. It is ignoring the LIS the same way that the DP approach ignores it. (i.e notice how 2,5,8 remain same and others change)

- Is the solution correct ? If not can you please provide a counter-example.
- Please also let me know your "thought" process that led you to think of the counter-example, if possible. Would be of great help in future questions.

### Which leads me to the question i wanted to ask most -

How exactly do you figure out if your greedy solution is correct ? How do you realize that greedy wont work and you'll have to use dynamic programming ?

If the pseudo code is unclear for anyone,please let me know. I would be more than happy to submit the complete code.

Comment: What happens with input `5 6 7 3 4 5 6 7` ??.(3 changes needed at the beginning) One issue if that the greedy algorithm has a short-distance vision of the *past*

Comment: You can always compare your implementation against a slow full search of all possibilities.

Comment: @Damien yeah that explains it a bit, but even that's fixable if we do a similar decreasing sequence greedy after reversing the array(or even better make all the elements negative and then do the same greedy in original post ) and then taking minimum changes of the two methods.
Thanx nonetheless, can you answer the last question ? I get really confused in greedy proofs.

Comment: @MrSmith42 Do you mean write a brute-force way and try different possibilities ?

Comment: @Nemesis101 I mean: If you are not sure, if you greedy approach delivers the optimal answer, you can always search for the optimal answer bei a slow bute-force search for testing and compare if your greedy approch delivers the same or anothe (as goog) solution.